# "Date Filtering Issue with DAX in Power BI"

Tags: powerbi, dax

i have this measure

```
Quantity sold SENS 2 =
 CALCULATE(
 SUM('MVTL'[REFQTE]),ALLEXCEPT(MVTL,Dim_Article[REF]),
FILTER(
       'MVTL',
        MVTL[TICOD] = "C" && 'MVTL'[PICOD] >2 && 'MVTL'[SENS]=2 && Dim_Date_MVTL[Date]>= min('Dim_Date_MVTL'[Date]) && Dim_Date_MVTL[Date]<=MAX('Dim_Date_MVTL'[Date])
    ),
FILTER(
    'Dim_Article' ,
    Dim_Article[APFRAIS] = 0
)
)
```

the error is  :

> A single value for column 'Date' in table 'Dim_Date_MVTL' cannot be
> determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column
> that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as
> min, max, count, or sum to get a single result

how fix this error please

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is because within your measure, you are comparing `Dim_Date_MVTL[Date]` against the results of aggregate functions `MIN('Dim_Date_MVTL'[Date])` and `MAX('Dim_Date_MVTL'[Date])`. However, the context within which the comparison is being made might not have a single value for `Dim_Date_MVTL[Date]`.

```
Quantity sold SENS 2 =
VAR MinDate = MIN('Dim_Date_MVTL'[Date])
VAR MaxDate = MAX('Dim_Date_MVTL'[Date])

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM('MVTL'[REFQTE]),
    ALLEXCEPT(MVTL,Dim_Article[REF]),
    FILTER(
        'MVTL',
        MVTL[TICOD] = "C" && 
        'MVTL'[PICOD] > 2 && 
        'MVTL'[SENS] = 2 && 
        Dim_Date_MVTL[Date] >= MinDate && 
        Dim_Date_MVTL[Date] <= MaxDate
    ),
    FILTER(
        'Dim_Article',
        Dim_Article[APFRAIS] = 0
    )
)
```